# toggling table rows but every tables rows are effected from one id

Tags: jquery

I am toggling table rows at the moment, however only the first entry is clickable and when that is clicked every single row in all of my tables are hidden..

I would like some help in figuring out how to make it so that when the text of each table is clicked only that tables rows are effected. not every tables in the loop.

this is what my code looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Catalogue">
     <html>
     <header>
        <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
            $('#toggle').click(function() {
            $('td:nth-last-child(-n + 1):nth-child(3n + 1)').toggle();                
       });
    });
    </script>


    </header>
     <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="Talents">
        <xsl:if test="Talent != ''">
            <table border="0" width="550">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="80%">

                    <b id="toggle"><xsl:value-of select="Talent"/></b></td>

                    <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="20%" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="Cost"/>
                    <xsl:text>  -  </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Type"/></td>
                 </tr>

                <xsl:if test="Prerequisite != ''">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><xsl:value-of select="Prerequisite"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:if>   

                <xsl:if test="Action != ''">
                <tr id="rowToClick" style="display:none">
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#E0E0E0"><xsl:value-of select="Action"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="Description != ''">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#EBEBEB"><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:if>

            </table>
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </body>
     </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _so that when the text of each table is clicked_.. Do you have multiple tables ?

Comment: yup, there are about 80 tables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following function:

```
$(function() {
        $('table tr b').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().toggle();                
   });
});
```

Note: this will add a handler to every b-tag that's inside a row.
Upon clicking that tag, the parent row gets toggled.

However, I don't understand why you would want it to toggle. Since the first time it's hidden, there's no way you can toggle it again (it's hidden so not clickable anymore)

**EDIT** OP wants the first row of the table to toggle the rest of the rows:

```
$(function() {
            $('table tr').not(":first-child").hide();  // hides the other rows on page load
            $('table tr:first-child').click(function() {
                $(this).siblings().toggle();                
       });
    });
```

Reflected in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kennethtruyers/g52xk/6/

Comment: okay I made a mistake in **<tr id="rowToClick" style="display:none">** was from some old code.. so effectivly i need the rows to be hidden on start up then when i click the parent row it should show the hiddle rows then if its clicked again it should show them again.

Comment: What do you mean with "parent"? You have no parent child relations for rows in your code. Do you mean the next row?

Comment: yea sorry bad wording. So I need the first row of each table to be able to show and hide the rows beneath it... at the moment I can show and hide every tables row using the first tables first row.... its really weird.

Comment: OK, so I understand you want to first row of the table to toggle the rest of the rows, correct? I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: yep.. so every tables first row controlls the other rows in that same table.. hope that makes sense.

Comment: see what happens when there are two tables .. the second one dosnt work the same...http://jsfiddle.net/g52xk/3/

Comment: OK, got it. You need to get the first child. I updated the answer and the fiddle

Comment: whooo hooo!!! thats perfect.. one last question.. how do i load the page with the rows i want hidden hidden at first.. instead of showing

Comment: Added hiding of other rows to the answer and the fiddle. Please remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: boom! your a ledgend! I have been tring to get this working for the past 5 or 6 hrs.. and you just helped me get a good nights sleep LOL thanks a bunch! answer accepted too :)